# c# if catch exception of a new method, will GC collects this object?

Tags: c#, multithreading, garbage-collection

```
private void BeginListen()
{
    while (isWatch)
    {
        try
        {

            Socket newSocket = socket.Accept();
            ConnectionClient conn = new ConnectionClient(newSocket, ShowMsg, RemoveClientConnection, SendMsgToController);
            string strRemoteEndPoint = newSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
            if (dictConn.ContainsKey(strRemoteEndPoint.Substring(0, strRemoteEndPoint.LastIndexOf(":"))))
                dictConn[strRemoteEndPoint.Substring(0, strRemoteEndPoint.LastIndexOf(":"))].isRec = true;
            else
                dictConn.Add(strRemoteEndPoint.Substring(0, strRemoteEndPoint.LastIndexOf(":")), conn);
            UpdateControllerStatus(strRemoteEndPoint, " online");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionLog(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This method is used for listening.

If I use thread to create this method

```
myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(BeginListen));
myThread.IsBackground = true;
myThread.Start();
```

Will it be collected by GC when catching an exception?
Or do I need to add `GC.Collect();` manually in the catch?

Comment: Unclear what a `ConnectionClient` is and does. I can see no I/O happening on the socket. Since you store it in a Dictionary, the resource management can't happen here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What do you want to be collected? Well, generally you shouldn't call GC.Collect yourself.

I would leave it for the GC to collect the objects and reclaim memory resources. But when something implements IDisposable, you generally should use the `using` statement.

In the example provided, maybe you don't need to use a `using` statement, because the socket may be used later, also, maybe there is already some code to dispose the object inside your `ConnectionClient` class. Disposing it now could cause you problems.

But generally you can use the `using` statement to automatically handle the disposal of resources, eg opening file streams, creating memory streams, and so on.

To learn more about what the using statement does, [Click here.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6564/Understanding-the-using-statement-in-C)

Comment: The using should be around the .Accept(), if required at at all. It looks like something that may be used later.

Comment: Changed the code. Now I'm unable to do anything with the socket object in the catch block, but since the using statement surrounds the block with a `try{} finally{ obj.Dispose() }`, I don't think the socket can be used to do something at all.

Comment: There probably shouldn't be a `using()` here, the socket is stored and still has work to do.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The `ConnectionClient` might use it later.